# While Ajax is working well, media upload isn't showing the imagines

Tags: ajax, media

Look at the image below, it has no javascript errors, and media upload still spinning forever :(
I tried to install new Wordpress, also disabled all plugins, googled several times, I tried to do it all and still haven't fixed this error. Any other way to debug this issue?

[image: What are you waiting for????]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding the following code to your .htaccess can resolve!
PHP_value default_charset none
PHP_value output_handler none

Note: comment out the others code having utf-8

Comment: Awwwwwwwwesome!!!
You save my life :*